# Hibernate mixes stored procedure output parameters

Tags: hibernate, jpa, stored-procedures, oracle11g, wildfly

At work we've run into a problem that we cannot seem to solve.

We are using Wilfly 10, Hibernate 5.0.0.Final and an Oracle 11g database with stored procedures. I also want to note that the same problem happens with Wilfly 9 on Hibernate 4, so I think it might be a weird problem, and I wonder if anyone has encountered it before.

Whenever we call a stored procedure, Hibernate (using the JPA2.1 API) mixes the output parameters, but in a consistent way. Let me show you an example:

```
public ProcedureResult submitApplication(Long stageId) {
    StoredProcedureQuery query = em.createStoredProcedureQuery("qu_utl_java.submit_application");
    query.registerStoredProcedureParameter("p_ase_id", Long.class, ParameterMode.IN);
    query.registerStoredProcedureParameter("p_bypass_communication", String.class, ParameterMode.IN);
    query.registerStoredProcedureParameter("p_id", String.class, ParameterMode.OUT);
    query.registerStoredProcedureParameter("p_result", String.class, ParameterMode.OUT);
    query.registerStoredProcedureParameter("p_error_message", String.class, ParameterMode.OUT);

    query.setParameter("p_ase_id", stageId);
    query.setParameter("p_bypass_communication", "N");
    query.execute();

    ProcedureResult result = new ProcedureResult();
    result.setExecutionResult((String) query.getOutputParameterValue("p_result"));
    result.setResultID((String) query.getOutputParameterValue("p_id"));
    result.setErrorMessage((String) query.getOutputParameterValue("p_error_message"));

    return result;
}
```

In the code above, you would expect the p_result parameter to end up in the setExecutionResult(). However, this does not happen. This parameter ends up in the setResultID(). Even though they are named parameters they mix up, but in a very consistent way.

We can work around it by adjusting the code, since it is persistent on all environments, by switching the output parameters names to match the right one. However, we don't want to do that since it is a very ugly solution.

I shouldalso  note that when we call the procedure from Jboss 5 (which we are migrating from), it all works fine. The parameters end up in the right variable, so the procedure is not to blame. We tested this in pl/sql developer too.

It does not happen with every call, just with some, but on those it happens it is consistent. I also tried the plain hibernate implementation instead of the JPA api, but the result is the same.

This is our persistence file:

```
<persistence xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         version="2.1" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence"
         xsi:schemaLocation="
    http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence
    http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd">
    <persistence-unit name="CENSORED">
        <jta-data-source>java:jboss/datasources/CENSORED</jta-data-source>
        <properties>
            <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true" />
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

It does use the right dialect, since it shows this in the startup log:

```
10:06:04,310 INFO  [org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 25) HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect
```

I hope someone has run into the same problem and found a fix for it, or if we can find a fix and help others. Your help is appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Do any of the out params come back as null?

Comment: Yes one does. Could that be the problem?

Comment: Okay, so it has nothing to do with a null parameter or anything. It has to do with the order that you are registering parameters!
It should be the same order as what is defined in the oracle package. Really weird, since these are named parameters, but actually the order in which you register them is absolutely essential!

Comment: Ha! Actually the ordering issue was where I was going.  You may want to raise a ticket on the HHH JIRA to see their response, but as far as I know the order has always been the expected behavior.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For anyone having this issue in the future, here is the solution. I don't know if this is currently a bug in Hibernate or intended, but if this is your oracle procedure definition:

```
 procedure submit_application(p_ase_id                in qu_applications_stage.id%type,
                           p_id                    out varchar2,
                           p_result                out varchar2,
                           p_error_message         out varchar2,
                           p_bypass_communication  in  varchar2 default null);
```

Then you should the parameters in that order! In my case, I did the last parameter as the second, so all output parameters shifted place.

This was the code fix:

```
public ProcedureResult submitApplication(Long stageId) {
    StoredProcedureQuery query = em.createStoredProcedureQuery("qu_utl_java.submit_application");
    query.registerStoredProcedureParameter("p_ase_id", Long.class, ParameterMode.IN);
    query.registerStoredProcedureParameter("p_id", String.class, ParameterMode.OUT);
    query.registerStoredProcedureParameter("p_result", String.class, ParameterMode.OUT);
    query.registerStoredProcedureParameter("p_error_message", String.class, ParameterMode.OUT);
    query.registerStoredProcedureParameter("p_bypass_communication", String.class, ParameterMode.IN);

    query.setParameter("p_ase_id", stageId);
    query.setParameter("p_bypass_communication", "N");
    query.execute();

    ProcedureResult result = new ProcedureResult();
    result.setExecutionResult((String) query.getOutputParameterValue("p_result"));
    result.setResultID((String) query.getOutputParameterValue("p_id"));
    result.setErrorMessage((String) query.getOutputParameterValue("p_error_message"));

    return result;
}
```

I'll check with Hibernate if this is intended or a bug. Thanks for any input so far guys.